# while(rs.next()) does not returns all records but just the last one

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

in my case I am using `PreparedStatement` to select records from my DB: 
the number of rows selected is correct but just the last one is displayed.

My code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    DetailCaisse detailCaisse = new DetailCaisse();
    devise.setLibSiglDev(rs.getString("LIB_DEV_DEV"));
    devise.setLibSiglDev(rs.getString("LIB_SIGL_DEV"));
    devise.setCodDevDev(rs.getInt("cod_Dev_dev"));
    detailCaisse.setDevise(devise);
    deviseDispo.add(detailCaisse);
}
```

What should I use instead of `while(rs.next())` to correct the problem?

[image: this picture may help u to understand the prob]

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: `rs.next` is the correct method. You might aswell only store the last element by overriding the previous ones. But in order to find it there the code is lacking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your usage of `while(rs.next())`. The problem is that you keep overwriting the same `devise` instance with new values, thus losing the old ones. Instead, you should create a new instance on each iteration:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    DetailCaisse detailCaisse = new DetailCaisse();

    Devise devise = new Devise(); // Here!
    devise.setLibSiglDev(rs.getString("LIB_DEV_DEV"));
    devise.setLibSiglDev(rs.getString("LIB_SIGL_DEV"));
    devise.setCodDevDev(rs.getInt("cod_Dev_dev"));

    detailCaisse.setDevise(devise);

    deviseDispo.add(detailCaisse);
}
```

Comment: Also, notice the setLibSiglDev called twice, since it is prefixe set and not add, I doubt this is an array will multiple value.

Comment: @AxelH indeed! Copy-pasted from OP, but according to the column names, I'm guessing the first one should be a call to `setLibDevDev`, so something like that.

Comment: @AxelH  is not called twice , one is  `LIB_SIGL_DEV` and the other is `LIB_DEV_DEV ` :)

Comment: @khawlabelgacem Yes, two diffrent row of the resultSet but you use the same setter on your Devise. If the setter push the value into an Array, I use to call them addXXX and not setXXX

Answer (score 2):

Some parts of your code are missing in order to tell you in 100% what's the problem is, but it seems like you declare `devise` before the `while` loop and than you overrides its values on each iteration.
That is the reason why you have 3 results, but they are all the same.

Also, note that you are overriding `setLibSiglDev` inside the loop with 2 different values, it will only use `LIB_SIGL_DEV`.

Comment: yes, this is the problem I declared devise before the while loop; I have just correct it :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem that `detailCaisse.setDevise(devise);` take the same reference every iteration but the reference value change every iteration so display the iteration value you should make new `new Devise();` every iteration.

Answer (score -3):

> the number of rows selected is correct but just the last one is displayed.

You can't have it both ways. Either you counted all the rows correctly or you didn't. You did, and you couldn't possibly have got the correct count unless `while (rs.next())` wa working, *ergo* `while (rs.next())` is the correct code.

Clearly there is something wrong somewhere *else.*